# Request.ServerVariables return NULL

Tags: asp.net

I create an ASP.NET web application.

Why I got NULL for this code?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];
```

Web.config setting:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Try with Internet Explorer, I have come across cases where non Microsoft browsers do not handle windows authentication.